# Having problems creating a custom lookup function in excel. Issue with match and concatenated ranges

Tags: excel, vba, function, range, concatenation

I'm having some trouble with a large spreadsheet of mine. I bring in a lot of raw data into a data sheet, and then do a number of lookups across the data. Using built in functions I've come up with

```
=IF(ISNA(INDEX(Data!$L$7:$L$1100,MATCH(Data!$I$2&$B$199&$B29&Data!$J$5,Data!$K$7:$K$1100&Data!$J$7:$J$1100&Data!$I$7:$I$1100&Data!$N$7:$N$1100,0))),"0",INDEX(Data!$L$7:$L$1100,MATCH(Data!$I$2&$B$199&$B29&Data!$J$5,Data!$K$7:$K$1100&Data!$J$7:$J$1100&Data!$I$7:$I$1100&Data!$N$7:$N$1100,0)))
```

Not pretty! Basically it does the same lookup twice taking 4 variables, and matching them against 4 concatenated arrays, then uses the point as an index for the value I want.

I have 8 of these (slightly different) in each row of 4 sheets and 96 rows in each sheet. Editing them is a pain!

Due to the dataset growing hugely this month, the outer bands (x1100) have been surpassed (lesson learned, large is never enough). Unfortunately limitations of the function won't let me use L:L or anything useful like that.

I've tried rewriting the code as a user defined function where I can feed the 4 variables in, and get the answer back, but have failed dismally at combining the arrays.

I've given the ranges listed above in the original function names to make things easier (and have expanded them to use much wider range values), so I could rewrite all the functions to just use the named ranges, but that still leaves my stuck if I need to change the code.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    Function Windows_Util(itma As String, env As String)

v = "Windows Server" & env & itma & ""
r = Concat(Range("Utilchassis"))
r = r & Concat(Range("Utilenv"))
r = r & Concat(Range("UtilITMA"))
r = r & Concat(Range("UtilOS"))

m = WorksheetFunction.Match(v, r, 0)

i = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("Utilavg"), m)


If WorksheetFunction.IsNA(i) Then
    Windows_Util = 0
Else
    Windows_Util = i
End If

End Function


Function Concat(myRange As Range, Optional myDelimiter As String)

Dim r As Range

Application.Volatile

For Each r In myRange
   If Len(r.Text) Then
       Concat = Concat & IIf(Concat <> "", myDelimiter, "") & r.Text
   End If
Next

End Function
```

This doesn't work! Not only does it concatenate incorrectly (each range is concatenated separately, not combined row by row), it doesn't like some type in one of the queries. (debugging these things is not easy as the function actually completes (it doesn't have any syntax errors in it), so there are no built in step throughs I can use.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Hopefully I've given enough details to make sense of what I'm trying to do.

Cheers,

Steve

Comment: Match will produce an error when used in VBA, if there is no match. You might wish to try On Error Resume Next and test for an error, or you may wish to use the Find method of the range object.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
r = Range("Utilchassis,Utilenv,UtilITMA,UtilOS")
```

That would seem to achieve the same as your Concat function

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly how you would like the Ranges to be concatinated, but I think you should have a look at the [Application.Union(Range, Range, ...) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb178176.aspx).

In the example from the article:

```
Set bigRange = Application.Union(Range("Range1"), Range("Range2"))
```

See also the [Article in the Daily Dose of Excel by Tushar Mehta](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2007/08/17/two-new-range-functions-union-and-subtract/) where he describes the following custom Union(Range, Range) method that can better handle 'Nothing' (null) inputs:

```
Function Union(Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range) As Range
    If Rng1 Is Nothing Then
        Set Union = Rng2
    ElseIf Rng2 Is Nothing Then
        Set Union = Rng1
    Else
        Set Union = Application.Union(Rng1, Rng2)
    End If
End Function
```

If, instead, you are going to use string concatination of the range addresses, then you have to add the commas, as Barrowc is showing in his post. For example `Range("MyRange1, MyRange2")` would union the two ranges named "MyRange1" and "MyRange2", whereas a space separator without a comma, such as `Range("MyRange1 MyRange2")` would return the INTERSECTION (overlap) of these two ranges.

However, I would recommend avoiding the concatenation of string addresses and use the `Application.Union(Range, Range)` method instead.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

The MATCH function can be tricky to use in VBA when there is more than one criterion to match on. What is done in a worksheet -- matching criteria concatenated from different cells against an equal number of concatenated ranges, in both cases using the & operator -- is not achievable in VBA because the VBA "&" operator only takes strings as arguments, and because other ways of concatenating ranges in VBA, the Union function and the assignment via multiple address arguments to Range, don't seem to produce an array that will work with the VBA Match function.

However, it is possible to achieve the same effect by constructing a worksheet formula combining MATCH and array comparisons and then executing the formula using the VBA Evaluate function.  See my answer to  [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406340/excel-vba-type-mismatch-in-range-concatenation-for-multiple-range-match-attempt/14410770#14410770) for detail on how this approach works.

The following code essentially re-implements the original worksheet formula provided by Steve without depending upon previously named ranges in the worksheet or on criteria values specified in the code (as opposed to particular cells in the worksheet). It is written as a sub, but can be easily converted to a user-defined function.

```
  Sub x4match()

    Dim adr1 As String, adr2 As String, adr3 As String, adr4 As String
    Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, Rng3 As Range, Rng4 As Range
    Dim name1 As String, name2 As String, name3 As String, name4 As String
    Dim idx As Variant
    Dim resultRng As Range
    Dim result As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

       adr1 = "I2"
       adr2 = "B199"
       adr3 = "B29"
       adr4 = "J5"

       Set Rng1 = .Range("K7:K1100")
       Set Rng2 = .Range("J7:J1100")
       Set Rng3 = .Range("I7:I1100")
       Set Rng4 = .Range("N7:N1100")
       Set resultRng = .Range("L7:L1100")

       .Names.Add Name:="name1", RefersTo:=Rng1
       .Names.Add Name:="name2", RefersTo:=Rng2
       .Names.Add Name:="name3", RefersTo:=Rng3
       .Names.Add Name:="name4", RefersTo:=Rng4

       idx = Evaluate("IFERROR( MATCH(1, --(" & adr1 & "=name1) * --(" & _
                     adr2 & "=name2) * --(" & adr3 & "=name3) * --(" & _ 
                     adr4 & "=name4), 0), 0)")

       If idx <> 0 Then
          result = .Cells(resultRng.Row + idx - 1, resultRng.Column).Value
       End If

      .Names("name1").Delete
      .Names("name2").Delete
      .Names("name3").Delete
      .Names("name4").Delete

    End With

  End Sub
```